# Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function array-callback-return

Tags: reactjs

```
{all_product.map((e)=>{
            if(cartItems[e.id]>0){
                return(
                <div>
                <div className="cartitems-format">
                    <img src={e.image} alt="" className='carticon-product-icon'/>
                    <p>{e.name}</p>
                    <p>${e.new_price}</p>
                    <button className='cartitems-quantity'>{cartItems[e.id]}</button>
                    <p>{e.new_price*cartItems[e.id]}</p>
                    <img src={remove_icon} onClick={()=>{removeFromCart()}} alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
                )
            }
        })}
```

In the above it is showing the warning message and showing error in the webpage

Comment: And it tells you exactly what the problem is, so what's your _question_?

Answer (score 2):

`Array.map` expects to execute on each item of the array. From your code we can deduce execution on each item is conditional i.e based on the cart's content. A better approach would be to use `Array.reduce`.

```
{all_product.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (cartItems[e.id] > 0) {
      acc.push(
        <div>
          <div className="cartitems-format">
            <img src={e.image} alt="" className='carticon-product-icon' />
            <p>{e.name}</p>
            <p>${e.new_price}</p>
            <button className='cartitems-quantity'>{cartItems[e.id]}</button>
            <p>{e.new_price * cartItems[e.id]}</p>
            <img src={remove_icon} onClick={() => { removeFromCart() }} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return acc;
  }, [])}
```

Comment: Not resolved and show err at if condition and not showing warning message

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing? Can you copy and paste the console.error message

Comment: CartItems.jsx:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
    at CartItems.jsx:22:1
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at CartItems (CartItems.jsx:20:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)

Comment: The error can point to multiple issues. I will suggest to resolve this question as its already been answered and create a new question with all the information required for us to investigate.

Comment: No not resolved

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when the if condition does not evaluate to true, your arrow function does not indeed return anything. Try to return something in an else case

```
 {all_product.map((e)=>{
        if(cartItems[e.id]>0){
            return(
            <div>
            <div className="cartitems-format">
                <img src={e.image} alt="" className='carticon-product-icon'/>
                <p>{e.name}</p>
                <p>${e.new_price}</p>
                <button className='cartitems-quantity'>{cartItems[e.id]}</button>
                <p>{e.new_price*cartItems[e.id]}</p>
                <img src={remove_icon} onClick={()=>{removeFromCart()}} alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
            )
        }
        else{
         return(<></>)
        }
    })}
```

Comment: still it is showing Uncaught runtime errors in the browser

Comment: You could have other issues in your code, for example in `cartItems[e.id]` you could be accessing an index in the array that does not exist. Try changing the if into `if(cartItems.hasOwnProperty(e.id) && cartItems[e.id]>0)`, and simplify your code as much as possible in order to find the line that is causing it